# Authentication from Adfs2 into my gwt webapp using openam

Tags: gwt, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, openam

I am newbie to the Adfs and openam. And what I want to do is to login into my app if the credentails are present into the Adfs. So how should I go about it?

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best to go about this was to create a fedlet using the openam setting the adfs as the idp.